# How to embed Invite Friends dialog into page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, invite

I am currently developing a game for Facebook. The design of the game requires me to create a page where you can invite your Facebook friends.

I know I can generate the request dialog via a click, but I wanted to just have a list of friend's avatars on the page, which you can select and then have the request sent (after user click). It was (I think) possible with the old fb:serverFbml, since it created iframe with friends' list, but FBML is not supported anymore.

Is such customization supported by Facebook JS SDK (or JS/PHP SDK combo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons this can't be embedded, you need to use the dialog Facebook provides, most likely to prevent clickjacking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I wonder - how it's done in all those Flash games out there on Facebook? They have custom-looking dialogs and stuff.

Comment: They make their own, or use third party libraries, I believe there are several javascript libraries that offer such a dialog component but i'm not familiar with them